# Enforcing compatible mode for IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Executing my below code in IE browser and found look& feel  issue in rendering the content based on the included font-awesome-ie7.min.css.  Tried this code in IE8 browser mode with  document mode (IE8 &IE7 standards)

```
        <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/img/favicon.ico">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
    <!--[if IE 7]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
    <![endif]-->
```

Not rendering properly.

Comment: Not able to get your issue, Can you please share the code including doctype.

Comment: try adding  `type="text/css"`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MongoDB Clusters</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/img/favicon.ico">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
        <!--[if IE 7]>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
        <![endif]-->
        
 
<title>Services</title>

Comment: Also you should explain what is happening, and how it's different from what you expect.

Comment: FYI, X-UA-COMPATIBLE will only work if it is the very first tag in your head element, except for charset.  If you have a charset tag, it must be first, followed by x-ua-compatible, otherwise x-ua-compatible will not work.  Even when doing this, x-ua-compatible may not work in a metatag because of quirks in the way rendering works.  If you intend to use x-ua-compatible, it should be done through http header instead.  If you're developing new code, however, you should fix your code to work in all browsers, not rely on compatibility rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have included a stylesheet for IE7 and trying to view output on IE8 while css will not work on this. To get output on IE8 you should try writing like this...

```
<!--[if IE 8]>

<![endif]-->
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us what version of IE you're using to test. IE 11 dropped support for conditional comments so it won't matter what you have as a conditional in there.

I would use lte (less than or equal to) IE 8 if you want to load for 7 as well.

You should load the regular font awesome css asset before the conditional statement. Load order is important.